# Windows service program shuts down on log-off mode

Tags: c, windows-services

I am working on a service program that reads the event log which shows how many times the user failed to log-in.
From my code, once a user click the **switch profile** button and try to log-in again, it stops.
As far as I know, the service program should run still during the log-off mode, am I wrong?

Please let me know the reason and any idea is welcome.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Since your application is running in Session 0, it should be unaffected by logoffs. Please post some details of what your program is doing.